# Error while creating haar Classifier using OpenCV in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ubuntu-14.04

I'm refererring http://abhishek4273.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/opencv-haar-training/ to create the Haar Classifier in OpenCV, I have got the error in,

`$ perl createtrainsamples.pl positives.txt negatives.txt samples 200 "opencv_createsamples -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -maxxangle 1.1 -maxyangle 1.1 maxzangle 0.5 -maxidev 40 -w 20 -h 20"`

`opencv_createsamples -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -maxxangle 1.1 -maxyangle 1.1 maxzangle 0.5 -maxidev 40 -w 20 -h 20 -img ./pos/5.jpg -bg tmp -vec samples/5.jpg.vec -num 40`

`Info file name: (NULL)
Img file name: ./pos/5.jpg
Vec file name: samples/5.jpg.vec
BG  file name: tmp
Num: 40
BG color: 0
BG threshold: 0
Invert: FALSE
Max intensity deviation: 40
Max x angle: 1.1
Max y angle: 1.1
Max z angle: 0.5
Show samples: FALSE
Width: 20
Height: 20`

Create training samples from single image applying distortions...

`OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Quadrangle is nonconvex or degenerated.) in cvWarpPerspective, file /home/project/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.9/apps/haartraining/cvsamples.cpp, line 217`

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'

what():  `/home/project/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.9/apps/haartraining/cvsamples.cpp:217: error: (-5) Quadrangle is nonconvex or degenerated. in function cvWarpPerspective`

Above error generated for all the samples in positive folder.

Eventhough it generates error, it has created **8 samples.jpg.vec** files in the samples folder.

Actually i have passed 200 as my samples, but it is creating only 8 of those in samples folder and throwing above error, and if try to merge using,

`$./mergevec samples.txt samples.vec`

It shows following error,

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (elements_read == 1) in icvGetHaarTraininDataFromVecCallback, file cvhaartraining.cpp, line 1859
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  cvhaartraining.cpp:1859: error: (-215) elements_read == 1 in function icvGetHaarTraininDataFromVecCallback`

`Aborted (core dumped)`

If any one knows the answer for the following please do post it.